# Multiple Views in the same page MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, view

I want to display different **Views** on the same page in ASP.NET MVC technology . How can it be acheived.

I have data coming in from 2 different Tables and for that i have 2 different **Views** for display. How can I display both these views on one single page.

Is there a concept of a **View** within a view in MVC ? Or is there some provision for making a master view which can encapsualte multiple views. ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These link's will help you (first gain knowledge of Partial view)

1. http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/2IKW160912-Partial-View-in-Asp.net-MVC3-Razor.html
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/351867/Basics-of-ASP-NET-MVC3-Part-II
3. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/aravindbenator/mvc-3-razor-and-partial-view/

Comment: Thank you , these tutorials really helped :)

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC supports the ability to define **"partial view"** templates that can be used to encapsulate view rendering logic for a sub-portion of a page. "Partials" provide a useful way to define view rendering logic once, and then re-use it in multiple places across an application.

Refer:

[Re-use UI Using Master Pages and Partials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/nerddinner/re-use-ui-using-master-pages-and-partials)

[Creating Partial View](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1831-how-to-create-partial-views-mvc-tutorial-number-10.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  the aspx webforms has the Master page and then you use user controls .ascx files.

With MVC, the "master page" is by default under

```
Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml
```

Now you can also end up using the wonderful Twitter bootstrap and really start to make greater looking layouts with easy to use css etc..

Your controller can return

```
PartialViewResult
```

as mentioned by the other answers from the others, those links should get you on your way.