# MVC showing different sections of data using where clause in same view

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

[image: StudentInfo]

I am using ASP.NET MVC to build an application to show student info. We have stored student info in a SQL Server database table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.students
(
      studentid INT NOT NULL, 
      studentname VARCHAR(100),
      CourseName VARCHAR(500), 
      Quarter CHAR(2) 
);
```

Quarter values are Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4.

I know how to bring records from table using an entity data model and show all records in one single view. But do not know how to split it using  where clause on a single cshtml page for different quarters

As seen from the picture above, I want to show records in 4 different sections on the same page ordered by quarter. How can I do that?

Thank you 
MR

Comment: It's no clear what you are asking. How much of you application already exists? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @PeterSmith I just edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the multiple grid in mvc razor form with different data you can use either [multiple tables](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-data-in-Single-View-from-Multiple-Tables-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) or by combining [partial views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477676/multiple-views-in-the-same-page-mvc-asp-net).